# Easymock: mock is being executed

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, easymock

So its my first time to use EasyMock and I'm trying to add some unit tests to some legacy code.

The legacy code is in Spring 3.1 and I'm using EasyMock 3.4.

What I'm trying to accomplish here is to test a service (a method written in Spring) that calls a dao.

Here is the code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="comment")
public class CommentBO{


    public static CommentBO createNewComment(Integer clientNumber, Integer commentCategory){

    CommentBO bo = new CommentBO();
    bo.setClientNumber(clientNumber);
    bo.setCommentCategory(commentCategory);
    return bo;
    }
}

public interface AssessmentService {
    public CommentBO getComment(Integer clientNumber, Integer 
commentCategory);
}

public class AssessmentServiceImpl implements
    AssessmentService {

    @Resource(name = "com.client.assessment.bl.dao.AssessmentDao")
    private AssessmentDao assessmentDao;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public CommentBO getComment(Integer clientNumber,Integer commentCategory) {

    CommentBO comment = this.assessmentDao.getComment(
            clientNumber, commentCategory);

    if (comment != null && comment.getComments() != null) {
        comment.setComments(comment.getComments().replaceAll("<li>&bull;",
                "<li>"));
    }

    return comment;
}


public interface AssessmentDao {

    public CommentBO getComment(Integer clientNumber, Integer commentCategory);
}


@Repository(value = "com.client.assessment.bl.dao.AssessmentDao")
public class AssessmentDaoImpl implements AssessmentDao {

    @Override
    public CommentBO getComment(Integer clientNumber, Integer 
commentCategory) {
        Criteria criteria = 
this.getSession(false).createCriteria(CommentBO.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("clientNumber", clientNumber))
            .add(Restrictions.eq("commentCategory", commentCategory));

        if (criteria.list() != null && criteria.list().size() > 0) {
           return (CommentBO) criteria.list().get(0);
       }

       return null;
    }
}
```

Here is my unit test written in EasyMock

```
@SpringApplicationContext("classpath*:/com/client/assessment/**/*-context.xml")
public class AssessmentServiceTest extends UnitilsJUnit4   {

    @SpringBean("com.client.assessment.remote.AssessmentService")
    public AssessmentService assessmentService = null;

    @Test
    public void testGetComment(){

    Integer clientNumber = 1;
    Integer commentCategory = 1;
    CommentBO commentBO = CommentBO.createNewComment(clientNumber, commentCategory);

    AssessmentDao assessmentDao = EasyMock.createMock(AssessmentDao.class);

    EasyMock.expect(assessmentDao.getComment((Integer) anyObject(), (Integer) anyObject())).andReturn(commentBO).anyTimes();

    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(assessmentService, "assessmentDao", assessmentDao);

    EasyMock.replay(assessmentDao);

    CommentBO bo = assessmentService.getComment(clientNumber, commentCategory);

    assertThat( bo , instanceOf(CommentBO.class));
    }

}
```

So basically what is happening is, my unit test fails because the result of

```
assessmentService.getComment(clientNumber, commentCategory);
```

is null!

Yes it will be null if it will actually be executed because in the database there is no record with a clientNumber = 1 and commentCategory = 1.

That's why, I thought of mocking the said dao and forcing it to return a CommentBO object.

As I've said above, its my first time to use EasyMock, so am I missing something obvious here?  Do i need to mock the call inside the dao method (i.e. getComment of AssessmentDao)? But if I do that, I'll be force to mock the Criteria object etc which i think is bad practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current code should work. So the only possibility I see is that `getComment` is in fact final. If you remove the `anyTimes` and add a `verify` before the assert, you should see that a call is missing.

The only other possibility is that `ReflectionTestUtils` fails silently. So you still have the original spring bean injected. If you debug, you will easily see that the DAO injected in the service is not a mock.

I've rewrote your code underneath. It is perfectly working.

```
public interface AssessmentDao {
  CommentBO getComment(Integer clientNumber, Integer commentCategory);
}

public class AssessmentDaoImpl implements AssessmentDao {
  @Override
  public CommentBO getComment(Integer clientNumber, Integer commentCategory) {
    throw new AssertionError("Should not be called");
  }
}

public interface AssessmentService {
  CommentBO getComment(Integer clientNumber, Integer commentCategory);
}

public class AssessmentServiceImpl implements AssessmentService {

  private AssessmentDao assessmentDao;

  @Override
  public CommentBO getComment(Integer clientNumber, Integer commentCategory) {
    CommentBO comment = this.assessmentDao.getComment(clientNumber, commentCategory);

    if (comment != null && comment.getComments() != null) {
      comment.setComments(comment.getComments().replaceAll("<li>&bull;", "<li>"));
    }

    return comment;
  }
}

public class CommentBO {

  public static CommentBO createNewComment(Integer clientNumber, Integer commentCategory) {
    CommentBO bo = new CommentBO();
    bo.setClientNumber(clientNumber);
    bo.setCommentCategory(commentCategory);
    return bo;
  }

  private Integer clientNumber;
  private Integer commentCategory;
  private String comments;

  public Integer getClientNumber() {
    return clientNumber;
  }

  public void setClientNumber(Integer clientNumber) {
    this.clientNumber = clientNumber;
  }

  public Integer getCommentCategory() {
    return commentCategory;
  }

  public void setCommentCategory(Integer commentCategory) {
    this.commentCategory = commentCategory;
  }

  public String getComments() {
    return comments;
  }

  public void setComments(String comments) {
    this.comments = comments;
  }
}

public class ReflectionTestUtils {

  public static void setField(Object object, String fieldName, Object value) {
    try {
      Field field = object.getClass().getDeclaredField(fieldName);
      field.setAccessible(true);
      field.set(object, value);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }
}

public class AssessmentServiceTest   {

  public AssessmentService assessmentService = new AssessmentServiceImpl();

  @Test
  public void testGetComment(){

    Integer clientNumber = 1;
    Integer commentCategory = 1;
    CommentBO commentBO = CommentBO.createNewComment(clientNumber, commentCategory);

    AssessmentDao assessmentDao = EasyMock.createMock(AssessmentDao.class);

    expect(assessmentDao.getComment(anyObject(), anyObject())).andReturn(commentBO);

    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(assessmentService, "assessmentDao", assessmentDao);

    replay(assessmentDao);

    CommentBO bo = assessmentService.getComment(clientNumber, commentCategory);

    verify(assessmentDao);

    assertThat(bo , instanceOf(CommentBO.class));
  }

}
```

Comment: okay I edited the code. The AssessmentService.getComment is not a static call. It should be assessmentService.getComment. I tried putting in the EasyMock.verify(assessmentDao) and commenting out the assert part. The test pass successfully, so it means assessmentDao is being called. However, I still want to test that assertion part --- assertThat( bo , instanceOf(CommentBO.class))

Comment: I want to add as well that when I create a valid CommentBO, meaning when i create a CommentBO that has a clientNumber and commentCategory that exists in the db, the assert works ( assertThat( bo , instanceOf(CommentBO.class)) ) , but this is what makes me more confuse because I thought I'm mocking (or am I stubbing?) the  assessmentDao.getComment to return a CommentBO (regardless of the value of the clientnumber and commentcategory passed to the assessmentDao.getComment method)

Comment: Your attribute is called `assessmentDao` and your are getting the comment from `creditAssessmentDao`. I was considering them to be the same, but maybe they are not. Also, please use `createMock`, not `createNiceMock` to see the verify fail.

Comment: It is indeed assessmentDao, thats a typo mistake. And i'm already using EasyMock.createMock(). Now, as i've said in my comment above, I'm creating now a valid CommentBO so the assert is returning true now.  What I wanted to know is what happened to this now: EasyMock.expect(assessmentDao.getComment((Integer) anyObject(), (Integer) anyObject())).andReturn(commentBO).anyTimes(); verify() says that it is being called,  the moment I create a commentBO that is not existing in the db (lets say a clientnumber that is not found in the db), the assert will fail.

Comment: Oh! I missed the `anyTimes`. Please remove that. It means it can be 0. Without it, the `verify` will fail as it should. Then, I would debug to see if the `AssessmentDao` is a mock. It should unless there is something I really don't understand with Unitils. So the last possible thing is that `getComment` is final.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The culprit was this one @SpringBean , it is not instantiating the assessmentService properly, so inside the ReflectionTestUtils, i am getting a NoSuchFieldException for the assessmentDao. When i changed it to assessmentService = new AssessmentServiceImpl() , thats when it finally worked.

Comment: Great. It's better to instantiate it directly instead of going through the entire Spring instantiation process. So keep it like this.